# httpwebrequest posting json incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http

Edit: Ok, so it looks like posting as application/json needs to be handled server side separate than a form. Is there any better way to post a form in C# as a complicated object? String:String just doesn't cut it. For example, I want to be able to use Dictionary to produce:

```
{
 "data_map":{"some_value":1,"somevalue":"2"},
 "also_array_stuffs":["oh look","people might", "want to", "use arrays"],
 "integers_too":4
}
```

---OP---

I've looked on SO and other places. I'm just trying to POST a JSON string to a URL, but the server side keeps interpreting the content as a string instead of a query dict. We have other clients that aren't in c# that hit the server side fine (in HTML, JS, Objective-C, Java), but for some reason the POST data comes back wonky from the C# client.

C# source:

```
private static Dictionary<string,object> PostRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, object> vals)
{           
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseURL+url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter.Serialize(vals);
        //json = json.Substring(1,json.Length-1);

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Dictionary<string,object>  retval = JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(response);

            return retval;
        }
    }
    catch(WebException e)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

This gets called like:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{   
    Dictionary<string,object> test = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    test.Add("testing",3);
    test.Add("testing2","4");

    Dictionary<string,object> test2 =  PostRequest("unitytest/",test);          
    Console.WriteLine (test2["testing"]);
}
```

For whatever reason, this is the request object that gets passed though:

```
<WSGIRequest
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'{"testing":3,"testing2":"4"}': [u'']}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CELERY_LOADER': 'djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader',
 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '28',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': 'settings.local',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HISTTIMEFORMAT': '%F %T  ',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_HOST': '',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'RUN_MAIN': 'true',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_PORT': '9090',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2+',
 'SHELL': '/bin/sh',
 'SHLVL': '1',
 'SSH_TTY': '/dev/pts/0',
 'TERM': 'xterm',
 'TZ': 'UTC',
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f3c30158270>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'django.core.servers.basehttp.FileWrapper'>,
 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x405b4d0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
[18/Oct/2012 19:30:07] "POST /api/1.0/unitytest/ HTTP/1.0" 200 31
```

Some of the more sensitive data in the request has been removed, but is irrelevant

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you confirm that the json string is correct before it gets sent? i.e. print out the results of `JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter.Serialize(vals);
`.

Comment: It is correct. Looks like it may be a Django issue after all. I get the same results using http://hurl.it when I manually set the post body

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I hope I don't make a habit of answering my own questions.

So, Posting Json this way is different than a normal form submission. That means if your server side is expecting just a normal form submission it will not work. The C# code does as it's intended to do, but only submits a JSON string as the POST body. While this may be convenient for people who validate, clean, and handle raw input anyway, keep in mind that if you're using a normal web framework, you will have to write an alternate condition to accept the raw string.

If anybody has an idea how to do a form submission in C# containing objects more complex than a hashmap/dictionary of strings, then I will upvote your answer and give you lots of hugs. For now, this hacky nonsense will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, once, a long time ago I implemented a banking app front end, which, made massive use of JSON for communication between client and server.

It was a clean way to find complex object to and from the server, no need to make complex cleanup or raw string processing.

The key was using WebServices designed for ajax on the server side, your web server class should look like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://something.cool.com/")]
[ScriptService] // This is part of the magic
public class UserManagerService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod] // This is too a part of the magic
    public MyComplexObject MyMethod(MyComplexInput myParameter)
    {
        // Here you make your process, read, write, update the database, sms your boss, send a nuke, or whatever...

        // Return something to your awaiting client
        return new MyComplexObject();
    }

}
```

Now, on your client-side, set things up to make ASP.NET talk to you in JSON, I'm using JQuery for making the ajax requests.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: "UserManagerService.asmx/MyMethod", 
    data: { 
        myParameter:{
            prop1: 90,
            prop2: "Hallo",
            prop3: [1,2,3,4,5],
            prop4: {
                // Use the complexity you need.
            }
        }
    }, 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Anything that ASP want to return as the result for your ScriptMethod, is going to be contained in the response.d variable. So, let's say you are returning from the server a complex object, "response.d" is the reference to your object, you access all the object members using the dot notation as usual.

Comment: This is extremely off topic. The client is in C#, not javascript. Javascript isn't an option. It has to be C#, and in my paricular case I also need involving libraries to work with Unity and .Net, though those specifics weren't made clear. The server side, for what it's worth, is written in Django. I have no interest in ASP.suck